# Remove/Delete Custom Labels from Org

Tags: deployment, customlabel

Is there a way to remove Custom Labels from Salesforce Org, other than manually deleting them one by one?

Comment: Have you tried [destructive changes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_destructive_changes.htm)?

Comment: @Devendra wondering if you just delete from customlabel.xml  and save it via IDE it should work or try destructive XML

Comment: @MohithShrivastava no, package.xml can never delete data. You have to use destructive changes.

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs. I will try a  destructivechanges.xml .

Comment: did it work? I want to do it as well but does not seem to work...

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the custom label from the org using ant script.
In destructiveChanges.xml

```
<types>
    <members>name_of_label</members>
     <name>CustomLabel</name>
</types>
<version>42.0</version>
```